# Understanding the theorem 1.1 of a paper of D. Basile and A. Bella

Tags: general-topology

The paper is [here](http://rendiconti.dmi.units.it/volumi/38/02.pdf).

Given a collection of sets $\mathcal V$ and a set $A$,  $\mathcal V[A]=\{V \in \mathcal V: V\cap A\not= \emptyset\}.$

The **weak extent** of a topological space $X$, denoted by **$we(X)$**, is the smallest cardinal $\kappa$ such that for any open cover $\mathcal U$ of $X$ there exists a set $A\subseteq X$ such that $|A|\le \kappa$ and $\mathcal U[A]$ is  cover of $X$.

A cover $\mathcal V$ of  a set $X$ is **separating** if $\bigcap \mathcal V[x]=\{x\}$ for every $x\in X$.

The **point seperating weight** of a topological space $X$, denoted by **$psw(X)$**, is the smallest cardinal $\kappa$ such that there eists a separating open cover $\mathcal V$ of $X$ such that $|\mathcal V[x]|\le \kappa$ for every $x \in X$.

> **Theorem 1.1** If $X$ is a $T_1$ space, then $|X|\le we(X)^{psw(X)}$.

I don't know that how the authors construct the set $S_w$ for any $W \subseteq \mathcal V_\alpha$.

Could you help me?

Comment: It would be much appreciated if you could make your question as self-contained as possible.  There might come a time when the link you provide becomes stale, making it very difficult for future users to discern what this question was about.  In particular, include the part of the proof that you are having trouble understanding, and perhaps even the definitions of weak extent and point-separating weight of a space.

Comment: @ArthurFischer: Let me try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're asking about this part:

> for any $\mathcal W\subseteq \mathcal V_\alpha$ satisfying $\bigcap\mathcal W\ne\emptyset$, choose a non-empty set $S_{\mathcal W}\subseteq \bigcap\mathcal W$ in such a way that, for some $\mathcal W^*\supseteq\mathcal W$, the family $\{\mathcal V[x] : x\in S_\mathcal W\}$ is maximal with respect to the property that $\mathcal V[p]\cap\mathcal V[q]$ for distinct $p, q \in S_{\mathcal W}$.

Since $\bigcap\mathcal W\ne\emptyset$, we can choose some $x_0\in\bigcap\mathcal W$ and set $\mathcal W^*=\mathcal V[x_0]$. It is easy to see that $\mathcal W^*\supseteq \mathcal W$ directly from the definition of $\mathcal V[x_0]$. (All elements of $\mathcal W$ are sets from $\mathcal V$ that contain the point $x_0$.)

We already have one set $\mathcal V[x_0]$ and we add the sets of the form $\mathcal V[p]$ until no more sets can be added. (More formally you do this by Zorn's Lemma applied to the systems of sets having the form $\{\mathcal V[x] : x\in S\}$ and fulfilling the property $\mathcal V[p]\cap\mathcal V[q]=\mathcal W^*$ for $p\ne q$, $p,q\in S$.)

> Moreover, if there are distinct $p, q \in X$  satisfying $\mathcal V[p] \cap \mathcal V[q] =\mathcal W$, we will choose $S_{\mathcal W}$ in such a way that $\mathcal W^* = \mathcal W$ and $\{p, q\} \subseteq\mathcal S_{\mathcal W}$.

In this case the construction is basically the same, but you don't start with a single point $x_0$, but with two points $p$, $q$ instead.